# Pandas pythonic way to extract value and index from pd.Series as tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I define a Pandas DataFrame as `a = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'id':[2,1,4,3,0,5]})`, such that:

```
In [0]: import pandas as pd
In [1]: a = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'id':[2,1,4,3,0,5]})
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
   id  val
0   2    1
1   1    2
2   4    3
3   3    4
4   0    5
5   5    6
```

Also, I perform some functions over it, like `a.sort('id',inplace=True)`, such that:

```
In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
   id  val
4   0    5
1   1    2
0   2    1
3   3    4
2   4    3
5   5    6
```

Note how the index is unordered.

And after, I want to extract information by doing something like `a.val[a.id >=2]`, which returns a `pd.Series`:

```
In [4]: a.val[a.id >=2]
Out[4]: 
0    1
3    4
2    3
5    6
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

If I want to extract the first value of the `pd.Series` I do `a.val[a.id >= 2].iloc[0]`, and for the index `a.val[id >= 2].index[0]`, and put them as a tuple.

Is there a way to extract both values as a tuple in one line of code? Is there a pythonic way?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer:  I'm not a real pandas user (though I like to read pandas questions around here), so there could be a better way...

That said, if pandas doesn't provide a better way, I'd just write a function:

```
def extract_first(series):
    return series.iloc[0], series.index[0]

extract_first(a.val[a.id >= 2])
```

I would expect that this would allow you to execute the comparatively expensive indexing only once which could be helpful for larger series.

---

Looking at the [docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html?highlight=iteritems#pandas.Series.iteritems), it appears that you can also use `iteritems`:

```
next(a.val[a.id >= 2].iteritems())
```

Comment: and now I wait for [DSM](http://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) to come around and show me up with a much better answer . . .

Comment: I wait for a better way too. :)

Comment: @osjerick -- It looks like you can take the first value yielded from `iteritems`